# Proving the irrationality of $\sqrt{5} = x \sqrt{7} + y$

Tags: prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

I need to prove that there are no rational numbers $x, y$ that

$$\sqrt{5} = x \sqrt{7} + y$$

We know that square root of prime is irrational so $y = 5 - 7x$ so the only number for it to be rational is if $y = 0$ so $x = \frac{\sqrt{7}} {\sqrt {5}}$ but that is irrational or when $x = 0$, $y = \sqrt{5}$ which is irrational.

$x = \sqrt{5} - y \sqrt {7}$, so I'm stuck here.

Or I need to try to prove each at turn, like

1 case : let $x =$ blah blah and do it as irrational prime proof

2 case : let $y =$ ???

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume we have rationals $x,y$ such that $\sqrt{5} = x\sqrt{7} + y$.

Square both sides, we get $5 = 7x^2 + y^2 + 2xy\sqrt{7}$.

So $\sqrt{7} = {{5 - 7x^2 - y^2} \over {2xy}}$ which is rational, contradiction.

Comment: why RHS is rational?

Comment: Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, so closed under +,- and division.

Comment: Because $x,y$ are rational, and the rational numbers are closed under the operations of arithmetic.

Comment: aaa i get it now , thank you very much , i was doing it this way but then got stuck

Comment: addition: check that $xy \neq 0$ to justify the division.

Comment: In this proof is necesary make the cases when $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: yes but when x=0 or y=0 doesnt it disprove my question , because 0 is rational number???

Comment: It has to be ruled out. We cannot divide by $2xy$ otherwise, so you have to consider it. One case is easy: $x=0$, if $y = 0$ you need a slightly different argument, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y\in Q$, then $\sqrt 5= x\sqrt 7+y\implies \sqrt 5-y=x\sqrt 7\implies 5-2 y\sqrt 5 +y^2=7x^2\implies$  $$(-2 y)\sqrt 5=7x^2-5-y^2\in Q\implies y=0\implies$$ $$\sqrt 5=x\sqrt 7\implies x=\sqrt {5/7}\not \in Q$$contradicting $x\in Q$.

Comment: Why did let  y=0 ?

Comment: We got $ y=0$ because we got  $-2 y\sqrt 5\in Q$. That would make $\sqrt 5 \in Q$ if $y$ were non-zero.